# Compare file name to string in bash

Tags: bash

I'm creating a backup function to copy all files with an specific extension extension.

`files()` returns `'*'` `'+'` `'./'` when it has not found file results, so I'm trying to avoid the invalid `cp [* | + | ./] /backup` with an `if` but it only works for `*`.

```
function backupByExt {
  # $1 = extension $2 = searchPaths $3 = backPath
  ext=$1
  sp=$2
  bp=$3
  files=( "$sp" + *."$ext" )
  # printf 'Backing up %s files: %d\n' "$ext" "${#files[@]}"
  # loop over all the files having the current extension
  for f in "${files[@]}"
  do
    # printf 'File: %s bp: %s\n' "$f" "$bp"
    if [ "$f" != "*" ] && [ "$f" != "+" ] && [ "$f" != "./" ]; then
      cp "$f" "$bp"
    fi
  done
}
```

Comment: What's Python got to do with this - did you mean to tag it as `bash` ?

Comment: The "linux" tag isn't correct either, as should be obvious from its description.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
files=( "$sp" + *."$ext" )
```

looks wrong; the `+` will become the second element of the arrey.  You probably want

```
files=( "$sp"/*."$ext" )
```

The check for `!= *` can be omitted by `shopt -s nullglob`.

A `case` statement might be more readable than your `||` chain (which should be `&&`):

```
case $f in
  ./|\+|\*)  ;;
  *) cp "$f" "$bp/" ;;
esac
```

Comment: 'shopt -s nullglob' is equivalent to '+nullglob'?

Comment: yes; you are right.  `-s` is correct; `+` does not work

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `&&` (`and`).

This is because you only want to print the file if the results are not `*`, `+` or `./`. This means that you want to make sure all three of those conditions are `False`, and the way you do this is by using `&&`.

Currently, your code isn't working as it first checks if results are not equal to `*`. If this condition is `True`, there is no need to evaluate the other two conditions so `bash` will just go to the next line of code (ignoring your other conditions as you're using `or`).